# azure devops pipeline set all function app settings to False

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions

We have an Azure Devops pipeline that deploys a function and set the app settings via this command:

```
az functionapp config appsettings set --name "$(appName)" --resource-group "$(resourceGroup)" --settings "@$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/app-settings-${{ parameters.environmentShort }}.json"
```

Since a few weeks ago, suddenly this command sets all the app settings value to "False".

[image]

The appsettings file in the artifact location contains the correct values. So it's really unclear where these False values are coming from.

Has anyone experienced this before? Or any idea what happened here?

If I run the same command from my local machine, the app setttings values are set correctly so I don't think it's caused by the file either.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After checking the build agents, finally found out that it's caused by an update in the build agent's image, which uses Azure CLI 2.24 which causes this issue.
There's a hotfix in CLI 2.24.1 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/release-notes-azure-cli?tabs=azure-cli#june-01-2021 but the question is when Microsoft's will upgrade their image to use this